# Azure Function (Python) - Many Duplication Error

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I'm writing a Azure Function with Python (3.10.5) and I need to read JSON files from Azure Storage which is saved as a JSON file and categorized with subfolder like "year/month/day/hour/minute/xyz.json"

The function is running without any error but it is reading every previous line when there is a new line added to the JSON file, which is collecting all events for an hour. I couldn't find a way to let the function to read only previous lines one time and after that only read the newly added lines to the JSON file.

Below is the script which is not running correct. For example, if one JSON file has 50 lines, the function should insert 50 rows to the database table. But the function reads the file again and again when there is a new line, and inserts hundreds of lines to the database.

```
def main(blobEvents: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {blobEvents.name}"
                 f"Blob Size: {blobEvents.length} bytes")

    dbConn = os.getenv("SqlConnectionString")
    blobString = blobEvents.read().decode('utf-8')

    data = pd.read_json(blobString, lines=True)

    for index,item in data.iterrows():
        #logging.info(item)
        index = 0
        
        eventTime = pd.to_datetime(item["time"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
        appVersion = item['Properties']['ApplicationVersion']
                
        try:
            with pyodbc.connect(dbConn) as conn:
                #conn.autocommit = True
                with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventTest] (eventName, applicationVersion) VALUES (?, ?);") 
                    values = [eventName, str(appVersion)]
                    cursor.execute(SQLCommand, values)
                    conn.commit()
                    conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            error = str(e)
            #print("ERROR MESSAGE", error)
```